# Is it wrong to store a number inside an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning how to integrate Javascript into HTML, and I had an idea for some odd code. I can't say for certain if there is something wrong with it.

My goal was to create a counter that is displayed on the page that starts at 1 and increases every time a function is called.

My original code was something like this:

```html
<p id="counter"></p>

<script>
var turn = 1, turn_counter = document.getElementById('counter');
turn_counter.innerHTML = turn;

function increase() {
  turn++
  turn_counter.innerHTML = turn;
}
</script>
```

The variable `turn` would keep track of a number, and `turn_counter` would keep track of the `<p>` tag. The contents of this tag were then set to `turn`. When the function `increase()` was called it would increment `turn` and then adjust the tag to match.

However I realized there was a potential simpler solution:

```html
<p id="counter">1</p>

<script>
var turn_counter = document.getElementById('counter');

function increase() {
  turn_counter.innerHTML++
}
</script>
```

This writes "1" inside the `<p>` tag and then sets the variable `turn_counter` to that tag. Then whenever the `increase()` function is called it simply increases the number inside the tag.

While both solutions work, I feel like there must be some problem with using the second one. Something about storing a variable inside an HTML tag doesn't feel right. So are there any problems with the second solution?

(Also if there are any better ways of doing this I'd be open to them. I'm still very new to this.)

Comment: If you don't need to display your variable, you could simply use `<input type="hidden" />`

Comment: It’s fundamentally easier to have an “internal state” in Javascript and just manipulate it in Javascript, and have the DOM as a *view* only which gets updated occasionally, than mixing the DOM into the core business logic. You’ll notice this more as you try to write more complex code, and will want to adjust and move around your UI more…

Comment: Both methods seem fine to me, although in the second one you should replace `.innerHTML` by `.textContent`. This will be much more lightweight and the DOM element won't have to be rebuilt at every increment.

Comment: Let me ask a more fundamental, but related question: Does that element make sense in the document without JavaScript? If not, JS should generate the element altogether (progressive enhancement), and I guess then the solution with state in JS becomes even more obvious.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann What is the difference between `.innerHTML` and `.textContent`, and why is the latter better in this context?

Comment: When `.innerHTML` is set with a new string value it triggers a full HTML parsing of that string, whereas, when you set `textContent` the string will be used as the only text node in the element but it will not be HTML-parsed as such. Possible `<` and `>` will be translated to `&lt;` and `&gt;` but otherwise the text will be left "as is".

Comment: In this specific simple case I am not against the second version. This would possibly not scale for more components or complex state. But in this specific context it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

While with the first solution you are actually storing a variable in Javascript in the second example you are making use of Javascript "quirks" but it's probably not what you wanted.

When you read the innerHTML of the counter div, Javascript finds a string number, as "1" but since "1" is shallow equal to 1, Javascript tries to apply mathematics to it and does what you asked.

Is it working? Yes.
Is it bad? Also yes.

But why is it working? It's working because of Javascript's type coercion and type casting based on that.

Why is it bad? It's not bad because of type coercion, it's not good because of the fact that you are saving your application state on the UI layer which is doable but not a good op.

You are not storing a variable in this case, you are just making use of Javascript weird behaviors. You could potentially parse the innerHTML to turn it into a number but it's yet far from a solution as you wouldn't properly save "state" for your javascript application, which is where to logic resides!

You could see HTML as the UI layer (unstyled) but you want to keep the logic (like variable declaration and usage) inside Javascript.

As proposed by @GrafiCode in the comments, you could

```
const whatAmI_1 = div.innerHTML + 1
const whatAmI_2 = div.innerHTML++

typeof whatAmI_1 // string, 11
typeof whatAmI_2 // number, 2
```

This is because the increment operator (++) parses the string, casts it to a number and applies the necessary incrementation while the + 1 is seen as a concatenation of strings as the second value (+1) gets parsed and casted to string by Javascript.

@Wiktor Zychla noted that maybe the word "quirks" is not explicative enough about the choices made by Javascript. Type coercion is not something bad or wrong, it's part of Javascript and if you know what it is and how to use it, you can do a lot of things.

Comment: Even if OP properly parsed the string back to a number first… it’s still bad for other reasons.

Comment: Yeah, because they are not actually storing a state, as I wrote, they are just making use of Javascript weird ways

Comment: just to clarify the "weirdness": the increment operator (++) automatically casts the value to "number" format, it works fine in this case since OP is passing a number in form of a string. Instead, this: `turn_counter.innerHTML = turn_counter.innerHTML + 1` would result in `11` and such.

Comment: @GrafiCode edited answer with your comment, thank you

Comment: JavaScript type coercions are not "quirks" and are not "bad" or "good". The mechanism is not [specific to JavaScript](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) and one of reasons behind it is the flexibility it gives when it comes to DOM model typing. An advice would be to try to understand the design and its background instead of being openly against it.

Comment: @WiktorZychla no one is openly against anything, really, but calling the way javascript behaves "quirks" makes it easier to read. If you do not intentionally know how javascript reasons around certain types you could potentially go and find yourself with a buggy application. I will edit the answer to also take in your comment.

Comment: Some say "this is the way", others "this is insane"... Pic related https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2019/07/best-js-meme-to-date-2.png

Comment: Thanks. Your "it is bad? yes" sounds exactly like a negative opinion which kind of contradicts the "no one is openly against". Just saying.

Comment: Well, the user is "saving state" of the application inside a DOM element, wouldn't you call it a bad op?

Comment: React DOM is storing component state inside DOM elements and it's definitely not bad. Sure, it's way more complicated than this here but anyway.

Comment: @WiktorZychla didnt know about this, so React DOM is storing state as a string inside a DOM element? Could you please share info or links about that? Im curious now

Comment: The state is not stored "as string" but as an actual value/reference and there are no coercions as far as I am aware. There are sparse resources on how its implemented under the hood so that such implementation details can be learned mostly from reading actual source code.